# Looping a menu to display after a choice

Tags: java, loops

So i have this code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class StudentGradeDriver
{

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter student name: ");
    String name = scanner.nextLine();
    StudentGrade grade = new StudentGrade(name);  

    System.out.println("Welcome to the Student Grade Interface!");
    System.out.println("You are modyfing the grades for John Doe");
    System.out.println("===============================================");
    System.out.println("(1)  Add homework score");
    System.out.println("(2)  Add passed Lab");
    System.out.println("(3)  Add midterm exam score");
    System.out.println("(4)  Set final exam score");
    System.out.println("(5)  Calculate final grade");
    System.out.println("(-1) Exit");
    System.out.println("===============================================");
    System.out.print("Please input your choice: ");
    int choice = scanner.nextInt();

while(true)
{  
   if (choice == 1);
  {
      System.out.println("Enter total points earned: ");
      double _hwEarned = scanner.nextDouble();

      System.out.println("Enter total points possible: ");
      double _hwPossible = scanner.nextDouble();

      grade.addHomework(_hwEarned, _hwPossible);

      System.out.println("Welcome to the Student Grade Interface!");
      System.out.println("You are modyfing the grades for John Doe");
      System.out.println("===============================================");
      System.out.println("(1)  Add homework score");
      System.out.println("(2)  Add passed Lab");
      System.out.println("(3)  Add midterm exam score");
      System.out.println("(4)  Set final exam score");
      System.out.println("(5)  Calculate final grade");
      System.out.println("(-1) Exit");
      System.out.println("===============================================");
      System.out.print("Please input your choice: ");
      choice = scanner.nextInt();
  }

  if (choice == 2)
  {
      System.out.println("A passed lab has been added for "
                             + "this student. ");

      grade.passedLab();
  }

  else if (choice == 3)
  {
      System.out.println("Enter total points earned for midterm: ");
      double _midEarned = scanner.nextDouble();

      System.out.println("Enter total points possible for midterm: ");
      double _midPossible = scanner.nextDouble();

      grade.addExam(_midEarned, _midPossible);

      System.out.println("Welcome to the Student Grade Interface!");
    System.out.println("You are modyfing the grades for John Doe");
    System.out.println("===============================================");
    System.out.println("(1)  Add homework score");
    System.out.println("(2)  Add passed Lab");
    System.out.println("(3)  Add midterm exam score");
    System.out.println("(4)  Set final exam score");
    System.out.println("(5)  Calculate final grade");
    System.out.println("(-1) Exit");
    System.out.println("===============================================");
    System.out.print("Please input your choice: ");
    choice = scanner.nextInt();

  } 

  else if (choice == 4)
  {
      System.out.println("Enter total points earned for final: ");
      double _finalEarned = scanner.nextDouble();

      grade.setFinalExam(_finalEarned);

    System.out.println("Welcome to the Student Grade Interface!");
    System.out.println("You are modyfing the grades for John Doe");
    System.out.println("===============================================");
    System.out.println("(1)  Add homework score");
    System.out.println("(2)  Add passed Lab");
    System.out.println("(3)  Add midterm exam score");
    System.out.println("(4)  Set final exam score");
    System.out.println("(5)  Calculate final grade");
    System.out.println("(-1) Exit");
    System.out.println("===============================================");
    System.out.print("Please input your choice: ");
    choice = scanner.nextInt();
  }

  else if (choice == 5)
  {
      System.out.println("The score for " + name + " is " 
                             + grade.getFinalScore());
  }
  else if(choice == -1)
  {
      break;
  }
 }

  }
 }
```

Is there an easier or another way to loop it so that the menu will display after choices 1, 3, 4, and 5, but not 2 and still exit when the user input is -1?
Also even with me copying and pasting the menu, it appears that the if (choice ==1) still executes after i have pressed a different number. After that execution and the menu pops up again, if i hit the same number it will then execute. 
For example when my first choice would be 3, however it would only execute if (choice == 1), my 2nd choice would then be 2 and that will execute if (choice == 2), and my 3rd choice would be 3 again, but it will just go back to if (choice == 1), would anyone know why this happens?
Any help willl be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You'll need to add a special condition and keep track of this special case (preferably via `boolean`)

Comment: Tip: instead of copying and pasting your menu, put all of your System.out.print and println statements into their own method and call the method when you need it executed:
public static void printMenu() { /* all of your print statements */ }

Comment: @WillNewton Yes, that would make this whole thing easier, but my professor doesn't want us to make a method but do it with loops instead, he just likes making life more complicated....

Comment: Your professor wants you to use copy-paste? That's like a parent making their kid smoke the whole pack.

Comment: Well, he wants us to use loops, and idk how else to make it all loop together without having to copy and paste

Comment: I'm talking about the menu where you list the options from 1-5. You can put **only** those print statements into their own method. This will not remove your need of loops. You will still have a loop.

Comment: @CyberneticTwerkGuruOrc can u elaborate on what you mean? I'm a complete noob at this.

Comment: Alright, I will see what I can do. Thanks!

Comment: @user3404391 Just so that we can all understand the program, why should the menu not be displayed for choice #2? Also, why does the user not enter new input after choice #2?

Comment: The prompt given for the assignment specifically just stated that the menu should not display again for choice #2 but for everything else. However since, you pointed that out, I forgot that I needed to prompt the user for another choice, so that would have been under choice #2.

Comment: So, the menu does not reappear however there will be a need to prompt the user for another choice. Sorry about that.

Comment: One thing that might help you out is checking the value of choice. You can write this statement after any time you set/mutate/change the value of choice:
System.out.print("The number you have entered is: " + choice);

Comment: Thank you so much for the input. I emailed my prof and he actually lets us use a method so I have changed it into a method which makes it look a lot better than copying and pasting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not quite sure what you're trying to do, but I see you have a while loop and your first choice if statement is separate from your 2nd choice if statement. Did you mean to do else if(choice == 2) or am i misunderstanding what you're trying to do?

Comment: That was an error, I mistakenly put the semicolon there.

Comment: @user3404391 Good spot with the semi-colon, but I think what this answer means is that maybe you meant your condition `if(choice == 2)` to really be `else if(choice == 2)`

Comment: Oh, yes I have changed that i was confused because the semicolon was there it didn't let me do the else if and when I removed it I was able to make it else if

Comment: It works now. I have changed my coding if you guys want I can post it up for review

Comment: If that fixed the solution, feel free to choose my answer.